# enable/disable input field depending on checkbox status

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3, icheck

I have a problem disabling an input field when a checkbox is checked with a plugin called iCheck (http://fronteed.com/iCheck/).

Note: my code is working when the iCheck plugin is not used.

**Working example without iCheck:**
http://jsbin.com/gusewu/1/

**NOT working example when iCheck is included:** 
http://jsbin.com/ludiqi/1/

Any help on debugging this would be appreciated. I've been on this for 2 days now. :-/

Comment: Both examples are the same.

Comment: Works for me on both cases...

Comment: Both examples are working for me...

Comment: sorry updated the second link to reflect icheck plugin not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of `ifChanged` custom event:

```
$('input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-blue',
    radioClass: 'iradio_flat'
})
.on('ifChanged', function() {
    $('#upload_image:input').prop('disabled', this.checked);
})
.trigger('ifChanged');
```

#### Demo: http://jsbin.com/neheqocilu/2/edit

Comment: This works. However I have another issue now. If the checkbox is checked already the fields are not staying disabled (you need to check the checkbox again). I'm assuming I need to use a "else" function? if so I would I use it? (sorry i'm totally lost with scripting)

Comment: it doesn't work on my case with ifChanged, I had to use .trigger('ifChecked'); However if  I refresh the page it does work if I leave the page and then go back to it it will NOT save the disabled state. How can this be addressed?

Comment: It's hard to say. I'm not sure I understand the issue and when it happens. Is it preprodusable somehow so I could check?

Comment: I found the problem. I used a class. Like this: $(".test_priv1").on('ifChanged', function() {
      jQuery('.av-option:input').prop('disabled', this.checked);
    })
  .trigger('ifChanged'); Now works as you have it on the demo. Thanks so much!!

Comment: No problem! Feel free to get back if you have other issues.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong... iCheck overrided all those events and has own ones, all listed [here](https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck#callbacks)

```
$('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
  alert(event.type + ' callback');
});
```

Comment: it works I just didn't know how to do it. I have another issue now. See my comment above. Any idea on how I could do the if or else statements?